# Zomato api how to get restaurant website url?

Tags: json, api

I am creating a react app and I am using Zomato api for restaurants. I was able to display the search results in the app and link to a single page with specific restaurant details. I wanted to fill up the single restaurant page with name, link to restaurant website, address, photo gallery, etc. I already have the rest of the info in the restaurant json. However. I couldn't find any info to link to the restaurant website. All I could find is several links to zomato page with info for the specific website and on this page, there's the link to the restaurant website...

Here's the specific restaurant json I got from zomato api:

```
R: {has_menu_status: {…}, res_id: 16935822}
all_reviews: {reviews: Array(3)}
all_reviews_count: 3
apikey: ""
average_cost_for_two: 30
book_again_url: ""
book_form_web_view_url: ""
cuisines: "Drinks Only"
currency: "$"
deeplink: "zomato://restaurant/16935822"
establishment: ["Lounge"]
events_url: "https://www.zomato.com/miami/blackbird-ordinary-downtown-miami/events#tabtop?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1"
featured_image: "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/reviews_photos/607/4edc23f93d257fbed50f184d8c920607_1503580424.png?fit=around%7C640%3A640&crop=640%3A640%3B%2A%2C%2A"
has_online_delivery: 0
has_table_booking: 0
highlights: (15) ["Credit Card", "Lunch", "Serves Alcohol", "Cash", "Dinner", "Live Music", "Outdoor Seating", "Live Entertainment", "Fullbar", "Valet Parking Available", "Indoor Seating", "Nightlife", "Wine", "Serves Cocktails", "Street Parking"]
id: "16935822"
include_bogo_offers: true
is_book_form_web_view: 0
is_delivering_now: 0
is_table_reservation_supported: 0
is_zomato_book_res: 0
location: {address: "729 SW 1st Avenue, Downtown Miami, Miami 33130", locality: "Downtown Miami", city: "Miami", city_id: 291, latitude: "25.7667186000", …}
menu_url: "https://www.zomato.com/miami/blackbird-ordinary-downtown-miami/menu?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1&openSwipeBox=menu&showMinimal=1#tabtop"
mezzo_provider: "OTHER"
name: "Blackbird Ordinary"
offers: []
opentable_support: 0
phone_numbers: "(305) 671-3307"
photo_count: 34
photos: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
photos_url: "https://www.zomato.com/miami/blackbird-ordinary-downtown-miami/photos?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1#tabtop"
price_range: 3
switch_to_order_menu: 0
thumb: "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/reviews_photos/607/4edc23f93d257fbed50f184d8c920607_1503580424.png?impolicy=newcropandfit&cropw=886&croph=886&cropoffsetx=169&cropoffsety=1&cropgravity=NorthWest&fitw=200&fith=200&fittype=ignore"
timings: "3 PM to 5 AM (Mon-Fri),5 PM to 5 AM (Sat-Sun)"
url: "https://www.zomato.com/miami/blackbird-ordinary-downtown-miami?utm_source=api_basic_user&utm_medium=api&utm_campaign=v2.1"
user_rating: {aggregate_rating: "3.3", rating_text: "Average", rating_color: "CDD614", rating_obj: {…}, votes: "14"}
__proto__: Object
```

I am begining to find out that I kinda don't like Zomato api, but it will take more time to switch over to something else....

Comment: I'd bet this isn't provided, because the intent of this API is to get you to drive traffic to Zomato. Letting you bypass their site would defeat its purpose.

Comment: bummer... What about yelp api? I've heard about it but haven't had time to check it out

Comment: I'd expect any of the free APIs to have a goal of sending you to their site, not the restaurants.

Comment: I guess someone will need to build an api that's free from brand influences......